# Linear Mapping using the range being contained in the kernel

Tags: linear-transformations

Suppose V is vector space and S,T ∈ L(V,V) are such that
range(S) ⊂ ker(T).

Prove (ST)(ST) = 0

Now, I know that this means that if you apply the linear transformation S to any v in V, then you get S(v) = 0. Apart from that, I am a little stuck as to how I should solve this problem... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: range(S)$\subset$ker(T) means that T annihilates everything in the image of  S. so you have $TS=0$, which means $(ST)(ST)=S(TS)T=0$

Comment: The thing I'm struggling to understand is how is TS defined? Are you multiplying both linear transformations?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Thank you :) @DavidHolden